# Value must match regex '^https?://([^@

Tags: proxy, visual-studio-code

I am trying to update my Settings by importing my proxy in my VSCode.

I get the following error:

```
Value must match regex '^https?://([^:]*(:[^@]*)?@)?([^:]+|\\[[:0-9a-fA-F]+\\])(:\\d+)?/?$|^$'
```

what I have under my settings is

```
"http.proxy": "http://user:sample.proxy.com:123"
"https.proxy": "http://user:sample.proxy.com:123"
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false
```

Is there something I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error gives you all the info you need; it doesn't match the required format.

Typically if you want to include a username and password for authentication it needs to be in the following format:

`http://<user>:<password>@<url><:port>`

```
"http.proxy": "http://user:password@sample.proxy.com:port#"
```

Comment: `123` is the port number

Comment: @rioV8 wasn't clear to me, but I'll adjust, thank you

Comment: I just saw the adjustment. It still works. I have question, it still works if I keep it as `"https.proxy": "http://user:password@sample.proxy.com:123"` and don't change user name and password, why is that?

Comment: It’s just a way to redirect traffic, it doesn’t actually have to be an https endpoint, that’s just where you point https traffic. If that makes sense @anibal-bojorquez